# How do I set up 0% VAT for shipping via BFPO Postcodes in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to setup Magento so VAT on BFPO Shipped orders are at 0% VAT.

All rules I setup are ignored and it keeps using the normal UK VAT Rule at 20%.

Or when I do get a rule to work, it then shows all products on the site without VAT.

Obviously I set it so the tax is calculated on the shipping address. But it seems to ignore this too.

Any suggestions on setting this rule?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to setup a UK tax rule with postcode rule of * at 20% VAT. Then another tax rule for postcodes with rule BFPO* at 0% VAT. Ensure both these rules are selected in the product tax class rules. When the user then sets their delivery address to contain BFPO, the site will automatically recalculate. Im not sure if it will change the price on the product page though (I think it should), but it certainly works on the cart. With regards to the products changing price and showing as ex vat, simply change your shipping quote address post code to a UK one and see if the prices return to including vat, they should do.

Here's our setup that works; (Might be worth clearing cookies and trying to retest again)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashley, thanks for your suggestion. I did this, and it still ignores the second tax rule for BFPO, just can't get it too work. Any further ideas? Be much appreciated!

Comment: Updated with pictures. This setup works for us, might be worth clearing cookies and retesting.

Comment: Thanks for the pics they have helped. Cleared all caches etc , but the product pages are still showing prices less vat. Even though I have said to include vat. Any further suggestions? Again thanks for the help so far

Comment: Have you set the shops tax calculation default address in the admin under system config. Put in a non BFPO address. It should display the frontend prices based on this default address. System->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Default Tax Destination Calculation. Clear your browser cookies and make sure your logged out and retest.

Comment: Ashley, you're a legend, it works thanks. I've got a couple of other Magento Querys that wondered if you might be interested in helping out with? More of upgrading Magento and checking its all ok to do so. Is this something you might be interested in at a later date? How can I contact outside of Stackoverflow? Cheers again!

Comment: Glad it's working. I don't freelance Im afraid, but more than happy than to discuss anything regarding magento through with you. My profile has a link to my Linked In page.

Comment: OK understand about freelancing. I'm not on Linked In page, will go and join then add you. If you don't mind me picking your brains occasionally then I'll be more than happy. Again thanks for the help

Comment: @Ash thanks for  the easy to follow screenshots but I tried BFPO and it won't save as 0 rate with the error "Rate Percent should be a positive number."